# plotting complex graph (ribbon like) in python (using Heatmap?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

This is my first post on StackOverflow. I've never asked here before because all of it found its answer by browsing here, except this one time.
I am trying to plot date to have a schematic representation but I am not sure what is the 'best way' to do it and how to achieve what I thought of.
I figured this is the best way to represent the dataset I have : 
[image: my example]
So each data has

- a x-axis start
- a x-axis end
- a y-axis value
- a z-axis value

My data are stored into csv file like

```
start | stop | y-value | z-value
```

I thought about using heatmap to do so but I am not sure if :

1. This is the best way to do it (The overlap can be problematic to handle)
2. is there is an easy way to do it  (should I manually add all the required point between start & stop?
3. If I want to highlight some data, can I change (just for some of it) the z-color scale?

I thought a little help from here might clarify things :)
Cheers,

Little update : The way I was heading is working. I am not sure whether is is the best aproach but at least it is working.
I still need to make formating better but this is more or less what one can get :
[image: first draft]

So, the way I implemented it is to build a matrix and for each data fill each discreet point of the matrix with the highest z-value.